# Rounded image shape using clip-path

Tags: css, css-shapes, clip-path

I want to have css clip-path like the below image

can someone help me

[image]

```css
img {
  clip-path: polygon(53% 0%, 100% 1%, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 55% 100%, 42% 65%, 0% 52%, 44% 36%);
  border-radius:0 100% 100% 0
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mask` can easily do this. It would be tricky to have curve with `clip-path`

```css
img {
  width:50%;
  border-radius:50%;
  -webkit-mask:
    radial-gradient(circle at top    left,transparent 45%,#fff 45.5%) top,
    radial-gradient(circle at bottom left,transparent 45%,#fff 45.5%) bottom;
  -webkit-mask-size:100% 50%;
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1012/800/800">
```

Another syntax:

```css
img {
  width:50%;
  border-radius:50%;
  -webkit-mask:
    radial-gradient(51% 51% at 0 0   ,transparent 99%,#fff),
    radial-gradient(51% 51% at 0 100%,transparent 99%,#fff);
  -webkit-mask-composite: destination-in;
  mask-composite:intersect;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1012/800/800">
```

Comment: Hi Temani Afif thanks a lot this is what exactly i was looking for

Comment: However if i use a different image resolution the shape getting stretched. use below image and see please

https://www.digital-photo-secrets.com/images/marble-column-front-of-building.jpg

Comment: @SureshR because you need a square shape so a square image or you cannot have what you are showing

Comment: Sorry for troubling you more @Temani Afif. Why there is a border on the left hand side of the shape. is there any way to control it?

Comment: @SureshR can you show me a screenshot, I don't see that border